# Should I unsubscribe from Cold Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I know that it's good practice to **unsubscribe** from Observable to prevent **memory leak**.

But if it's **Cold Observable** should I also unsubscribe from it?

For example one that is returned by `Http.get()`

Comment: You can use `.take(1)` to force the Obs to terminate and avoid memory leaks. So: `http.get(...).take(1)`

Comment: @AngularFrance if you look to sources https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/take.ts you will see that yes unsubscribe is called, but since its cold observable then complete will also be called, so there is no needs to say take 1 if only 1 will be returned

Comment: I have updated my answer :)

Comment: Cold observables don't have to complete. It's trivial to write a cold observable that never does. See also [interval](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval) and [timer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer). Subscribers are automatically unsubscribed from observables that complete or error - whether hot or cold. Otherwise, explicit unsubscription is required.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat. Interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to do it. The HTTP observable is calling complete immediately after the action is done.

From the source code [sources](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ff5a748b31ee73a6517e2f4220c920c73fbdd1fc/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L130) I can see that `unsubscribe` is called on error and on complete.

```
protected _error(err: any): void {
    this.destination.error(err);
    this.unsubscribe();
}

protected _complete(): void {
    this.destination.complete();
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

I went further and did a small experiment by adding `unsubscribe` with a timeout

```
var subscription = this.http.get(`apiurl`)
            .subscribe(response => {
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    debugger;
                    subscription.unsubscribe(); }, 30);
            });
```

If I step inside of `unsubscribe` to

```
 Subscriber.prototype.unsubscribe = function () {
        if (this.closed) { // this.closed is true
            return;
        }
        this.isStopped = true;
        _super.prototype.unsubscribe.call(this);
    };
```

then `this.closed == true`, which means `unsubscribe` was called before.

So yes, now I can say for sure you don't need to unsubscribe :)

Answer (score 6):

> Since Cold Observables are finite you dont have to unsubscribe.

### Unsubscribe when:

- Infinite Obesrvables, ex. interval()
- If subscribed to (Subject, BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, AsyncSubject)

> In case of ReplaySubject you should unsubscribe if it cache life time is not provided
>
> In case of AsyncSubject you should unsubscribe if it is not completed

- Websocket stream
- Abstract control ex. valueChanges()
- Renderer2.listen()
- Events streams ex. formEvent()
- NgRx Store

### Do not unsubscribe when:

- If stream is ending himself ex. of('1','2')
- Router events, all Observables from Router are unsubscribing them self
- AsyncPipe
- Finite Observable ex. http.get()
- EventEmmiter

#### Subscribe have to be unsubscribed if it would not hit complete or error.

If I am wrong or missing something please let me know.
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000843/347833) for Volodymyr Bilyachat:

You should not unsubscribe from the HTTP observables. For example, the [request](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/27da7338ea8f3bf5336d77ed1877cfa6a1974d52/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L486) method from the HTTP service uses the `Observable.of()`

The `Observable.of()` returns a new `Observable` and after execution calls the `complete` method. This can be checked with the following [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/eejrh7?file=index.ts):

```
of([1, 2, 3])
  .subscribe({
    next: value => console.log('next:', value),
    error: err => console.log('error:', err),
    complete: () => console.log('the end'),
  });
```

As mentioned above, while executing the `complete` method, unsubscribe is called ([source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ff5a748b31ee73a6517e2f4220c920c73fbdd1fc/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L130)):

```
protected _error(err: any): void {
    this.destination.error(err);
    this.unsubscribe();
}

protected _complete(): void {
    this.destination.complete();
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It is definitely the best practice to free the used memory in javascript just like other programming languages.

Since you are using angular 2 you can use **ngOnDestroy** life cycle hook to achieve as this method is executed when the component loses its scope.

Assuming that you use a below snippet to subscribe to a data

```
subscription = this._http.getMethod('...')
                    .subscribe(response => this.responses = response,
                    error =>this.errorMessage =<any> error)
```

You should be using **importing** OnDestroy lifecycle hook from angular/core using an import statement.

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core'
```

**implement** OnDestroy in your component as

```
export class MyComponent implements onDestroy {
     .............


     ngOnDestroy() {
          this.subscription.unsubscribe();
     }

}
```

Comment: Why? unsubscribe will do nothing

Comment: I suggested this to be a good practice to use **ngOnDestroy** for all removing memory leaks

Comment: Its not a good practice, you reccomend to add 3 lines of code why they are are not required. What if i have in interval or in a loop call to http what you would recommend to create array and unsubscribe?