# Typescript transform forkJoin results with pipe and cleanup

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

What is the best way transforming result of **forkJoin**() so in **subscribe**() method I can write something like this:

```
this.refreshGraph(dependencies,microservices);
```

Here is how it works right now:

```
  loadAll(): void {
    const dependencies = this.dependencyService.query();
    const microservices = this.microserviceService.query();


    forkJoin({dependencies, microservices})
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.refreshGraph(results.dependencies.body || [], results.microservices.body || []);
      });
  }

  refreshGraph(dependencies: IDependency[], microservices: IMicroservice[]): void {
  ...
  }
```

Do I need to store result of **forkJoin**().**subscribe**() in Subscription and unsubscribe manually when component is *destroyed*? *dependencyService* and *microserviceService* in my case just wrap **http**:

```
  query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get<IDependency[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
  }
```

Full source code is available [here](https://github.com/tillias/microservice-catalog/blob/c8156cd21bace5fccf254463fd6b98cdae613ef0/src/main/webapp/app/dashboard/dependency-dashboard/dependency-dashboard.component.ts#L109)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities thanks to this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom)

Using **zip**():

```
  loadAll(): void {
    zip(this.dependencyService.query(), this.microserviceService.query())
      .pipe(
        map(([dependencyResponse, microserviceResponse]) => {
          return {
            dependencies: dependencyResponse.body || [],
            microservices: microserviceResponse.body || []
          }
        })
      ).subscribe(results => {
      this.refreshGraph(results.dependencies, results.microservices);
    });
  }
```

or using **forkJoin**()

```
  loadAll(): void {
    const dependencies$ = this.dependencyService.query();
    const microservices$ = this.microserviceService.query();

    forkJoin({dependencies$, microservices$})
      .pipe(
        map(result => {
            return {
              dependencies: result.dependencies$.body || [],
              microservices: result.microservices$.body || []
            }
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.refreshGraph(results.dependencies, results.microservices);
      });
  }
```

Both work the same **in this particular situation** because source observable will emit only once (see comments from [Michael D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6513921/michael-d))

You don't need unsubscribe, because **http** is [finite observable](http://willtaylor.blog/rxjs-observables-hot-cold-explained) See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000535/should-i-unsubscribe-from-cold-observable)

Comment: 1). The unsubscribe could be skipped not because it's cold, but because the observable from Angular HttpClient completes after a single emission. But it could still hang in there if the request never emitted and there is no other way to complete (eg. using `timeout`).

Comment: 2). `zip` and `forkJoin` (and `combineLatest` for that matter) are not the same. `forkJoin` will only emit once and complete when all the source observables complete. `zip` and `combineLatest` are better suited for a stream of data. `zip` would emit when **each** observable has emitted once and `combineLatest` would emit when **any** of the observable emits. Also most imp. both `zip` and `combineLatest` would only start emitting after all the source obs. have emitted at least once.

Comment: thanks Michael, fixed to "finite" observable and provided additional link. regarding zip and forkJoin -> since http is finite here and always complete, I don't think it matters which one to call? Or do you think forkJoin() is more appropriate here?

Comment: Yes but only in specific cases like this one (where the source observable will emit only once). That needs to be mentioned as well. At the moment the answer only states _both work the same_.

Comment: Great, many thanks -> fixed. Now this looks like a perfect answer?

Answer (score 1):

it is just about the little bit of refactoring. You can transform the data either inside your `query()` method or you can do it inside your `loadAll()` method.

below is the one of the way you can rewrite your `loadAll()` method.

```
 loadAll(): void {
    const dependencies = this.dependencyService.query().pipe(map(result => result.body || []));
    const microservices = this.microserviceService.query().pipe(map(result => result.body || []));;


    forkJoin({dependencies, microservices}).subscribe(
       ({dependencies, microservices}) => this.refreshGraph(dependencies,microservices)
    );
  }
```

Remeber that if any of the inner observables supplied to forkJoin gives error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or have already completed.
So it is better to handle the error properly. You can catch the error and return an empty array like this.

```
 const dependencies = this.dependencyService.query().pipe(
  map(result => result.body || []),
  catchError(() => of ([]))
);
const microservices = this.microserviceService.query().pipe(
  map(result => result.body || []),
  catchError(() => of ([]))
);
```

And also you don't need to unsubscribe manually here because the observable is created by angular's httpClient service. see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043309/1160236). And the forkJoin will complete automatically once all the inner observables are completed. I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks sir it really helps! I'm not sure how to merge two answers now into one cause I answered myself a little bit earlier, also comments from Michael are helpful understanding this particular use-case

Comment: @tillias as I said this is just one of the solutions and not the only solution. I just tried to explain all the parts of your question. you can mark any answer as accepted that has worked for you.